# Perguntas referente a suporte de serviços terceiros

Tags: debate

Qual a política do Stack em relação a perguntas referente a resolução de problemas de serviços terceiros?

Exemplo: [alguém sabe como resolver um erro na hospedagem de site?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104838/algu%C3%A9m-sabe-como-resolver-um-erro-na-hospedagem-de-site)

O Stack faz parcerias ou negócios para "atender" tais serviços?

Pergunto isso de um ponto de vista comercial.

Se isso é permitido, por quê não cobrar por isso?

Nesse caso específico, a beneficiada é a Locaweb. Um de seus clientes provavelmente não conseguiu suporte adequado da empresa e recorreu ao stack para sanar a dúvida (mesmo que não tenha resolvido).

Então os usuários do stack dão o "suporte", de graça. Não houve custo para locaweb. Pelo contrário, houve lucro pois o cliente paga pelo serviço, o qual inclui o suporte que é inexistente ou falho a ponto do cliente vir resolver numa empresa terceira.

O foco desse tópico é a pergunta no primeiro parágrafro, no entanto, deixo uma sugestão de monetização. O Stack pagar, em dinheiro, aos membros que resolverem questões dessa natureza. Claro que deve ter um prévio acordo com a empresa terceira.

A ideia é que caso tenha perguntas desse tipo, de pedido de suporte a um serviço terceiro, apareceria um "selo" ou qualquer outra coisa que mostre que aquele tópico é patrocinado e quem resolver recebe pagamento pelo "suporte".

Comment: No SOen algumas tag são enfeitas(como a do android) as empresas pagam por isso. Acho que ninguém recomendaria a localweb pra nada.

Comment: Colocar dinheiro no meio é péssima idéia e, com certeza, vai ter apoio zero na [se]. Melhor tratar como off-topic.

Comment: Quanto ao ponto da monetização, realmente, a locaweb em geral sai ganhando. Mas não vejo isso com maus olhos, pois o propósito é fazer os usuários ganharem, não vejo problema em ela também ganhar. Além disso, ninguém daqui sai perdendo com isso, todos ganharam. E enfatizo que a própria SE sai ganhando, uma vez que (em especial com a locaweb) vários problemas são recorrentes e muitos dos usuários vem procurar soluções aqui. O mesmo se aplicaria no caso da Amazon por exemplo, em que há muitas perguntas no SOen. Agora, quanto ao fato de isso ser on-topic ou off-topic, daí já é outra história...